# Fix table cells in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adapt some parts of my web application for mobile devices, and I am currently working on the following form using Html/css.

[image: Form]

I came across this little problem concerning the table. In fact, I can't fix the size of the table cells. For the moment I am using the following code:

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
    <thead>
    <tr>                                           
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th style="width:10px" >Date d'ajout </th>
    <th style="width:10px">NOM DU FICHIER</th>
    <th style="width:10px">Ajouté par </th>             
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <th>19/22/2016 </th>
    <th>25_02_2016_file_name </th>
    <th>testla team Fsqsf qsfqsqsfqg qsdg sdgsdg sdsgd sdsd</th>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

so what's the right way to do it? thanks in advance

Comment: You could try this in css
`table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this below code it may help you.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="sample_editable_1">
    <thead>
      <tr>                                           
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th style="width:10px" >Date d'ajout </th>
        <th style="width:10px">NOM DU FICHIER</th>
        <th style="width:10px">Ajouté par </th>             
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <th>19/22/2016 </th>
      <th>25_02_2016_file_name </th>
      <th>testla team Fsqsf qsfqsqsfqg qsdg sdgsdg sdsgd sdsd</th>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The template I am using already uses Bootstrap. so I added the "table-responsive" class and it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use width="100%" and it will take up the full space of the parent div / span that it is in.

If you are developing for mobile I would recommend using Bootstrap if you know it / looking at it if you don't. It's a very handy library for HTML when developing mobile compatible webpages.

Comment: Actually I am already using a template that uses Bootstrap, but apparently it doesn't handle this case, so I wanted to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use a scroll for the table

```
table{overflow-x:auto}
```